# Trying to set a twig global variable for a function

Tags: 8, theming

I have a Twig function in my theme that sets a random ID. The function works well if I include the entire function within any given template and then render the variable for that `{{ randomID }}` in the same template.

However, I'd like to be able to call this variable globally. I made an include file with the function and then call it in another Twig template like so:

```
  {% include directory ~ '/templates/slices/random_id.html.twig' with { randomID : 'randomID' } %}
```

... but now when I print `{{ randomID }}` in a given template where the include file is called, I do not see the random id print. I think I am on the right track here but not quite there yet.

I used these pages for reference:

- http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/include.html
  http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/functions/include.html

Comment: I don't think the `{{ randomID }}` can be passed by `{% include ...`. I guess you can pass the value in the alternative way. `{% directory ~ '/templates/slices/random_id.html.twig'  with 'randomID’: randomID
%}`

Comment: If I just use directory, I get `Unknown "directory" tag`. If I stick with include directory, and update the syntax, it still does not seem to work but no errors. `{% directory ~ '/templates/slices/random_id.html.twig' with {'randomID' : randomID} %}`

Comment: What about `{% include '/templates/slices/random_id.html.twig' with randomID %}` ?

Comment: @OanaHulpoi - yes I tried that according to http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/include.html and it did not work either.

Comment: Do you try create Twig function. You can see [demo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9PeAfExNSDk)

Comment: Have you tried to include it with `@MY_THEME`? As example like `{% include '@MY_THEME/slices/random_id.html.twig' with { randomID : 'randomID' } %}` instead of the include via `directory`?